# Что делает и зачем нужен метод String.lastIndexOf()

Tags: java

Зачем нужен метод `lastIndexOf()` и в чём смысл его применения? (Желательно с примерами).

Я где-то читал, что этот метод возвращает номер последней встреченной позиции с указанным индексом,но я все равно тогда ничего не понял.

Comment: Мой вопрос изменили.Я хотел сказать,что я прочитал и НЕ понял.

Comment: "где-то читал" у вас с исходного текста есть. На этот вопрос нельзя ответить "Этот метод используется в этом и том случаях". Используется, когда надо. Вместо того, чтобы вручную проходить по всему массиву в поисках последнего вхождения, вам реализовали готовый метод для этого. Когда-нибудь понадобится.

Comment: @SlandShow: Нажмите на «править» и исправьте вопрос как надо. Это, в конце-концов, ваш вопрос.

Comment: @pavlofff: тогда уже `String#lastIndexOf()`.

Comment: @pavlofff: Синтаксис JavaDoc. Сейчас найду ссылку.

Comment: @pavlofff: Вот: http://download.java.net/jdk7u2/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#see («package.class#member is any valid program element name that is referenced -- a package, class, interface, constructor, method or field name -- except that the character ahead of the member name should be a hash character (#)»)

Comment: @pavlofff: Возможно, вы правы. Я видел и такой, и такой синтаксис, и не знаю, что принято у джавистов.

Comment: @VladD Да оставим как есть и предлагаю удалить наше небольшое исследование, как не относящееся к вопросу :)

Comment: @pavlofff: Думаю, модераторы скоро сами перенесут его в чат :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Данный метод (***public int lastIndexOf(String str)***) выдаёт порядковый номер символа на котором начинается твой искомый текст. К примеру:

```
String str = "Hello planet earth, you are a great planet.";
int n = str.lastIndexOf("earth");
```

Выдаст тебе 13. Потому что последний раз слово earth в тексте начинается с 13 позиции.

Если же ты будешь искать слово planet, то результат будет не 6, а 36.

```
String str = "Hello planet earth, you are a great planet.";
int n = str.lastIndexOf("planet");
```

Ибо слово planet встречается в строке 2 раза и последнее из них них начинается с 36й позиции.

В случае если элемент был не найден, то результатом будет -1.

Но осторожно - данный метод имеет 3 дальнейшие перегрузки:

- ***public int lastIndexOf(int ch)***

  - Поиск одного единственного символа
- ***public int lastIndexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)***

  - Поиск одного единственного символа начиная с символа номер fromIndex. Счёт происходит в обратном порядке.
- ***public int lastIndexOf(String str, int fromIndex)***

  - Аналогично предыдущему. Но происходит поиск не одного символа, а целой строки.

Comment: за место var написать string и будет ява...

Comment: И так все понятно.Человек постарался все нормально объяснить и у него это вышло.Спасибо ему за это!

Comment: @LEQADA: Теперь ява...

Comment: @WalterNuss, вот теперь точно ява)

Comment: Ах да... Пардоньте, я .NETчик, забыл, что в яве нет string :)

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что метод имеет 4 перегрузки, раз уж делаете справку по документации

Comment: @pavlofff: Да, стоит. Думал сделать это после работы.

Comment: @WalterNuss   А может ли возвращаемое этим методом число равняться  "- 1" ?

Comment: @SlandShow: да. -1 возвращается, когда искомый элемент не был найден.